# Android Webview Image not loaded

Tags: android, android-webview

I making a simple app with `WebView`. But some images didn't load.

Correct (in my pc):

[image]

Wrong (in emulator):

[image]

Correct:

[image]

Wrong: no banner

[image]

So I debugged with Chrome debug and found out my code was changed.

[image]

I don't add like `noscript` or `style="display:none;visibility:hidden;"`.

Who know how to fix this?

code is here

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar mPBar;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mPBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress01);
    WebSettings set = webView.getSettings();

    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    set.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.loadUrl("http://something.kr"); // 보여주고자 하는 주소

    //set.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    set.setSupportZoom(false);
    Log.i("DEBUG", set.getUserAgentString());

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());



    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress<100)
            {
                mPBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            else if (progress==100)
            {
                mPBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
            mPBar.setProgress(progress);
        }




    });}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            webView.clearCache(false);
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}

private class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if (url.startsWith("sms:")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        if (url.startsWith("kakaolink:")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }


        if(url.startsWith("tel")){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            i.setData(android.net.Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);

        }



        return true;




    }}
}
```

Comment: Are you loading the page from your assets or from the internet? Your .loadUrl() suggests the latter one. But often, content-loading problems with the WebView occur when displaying files from the asset folder and forgetting the `file:///android_asset/` part. So if it is the former one, you might check for this one.

Comment: @PhilLab Thanks for commenting. But It load page from Internet (a site)..

Answer (score 4):

From Android docs:

> Android 5.0 changes the default behavior for your app. If your app
>   targets API level 21 or higher: The system blocks **mixed content** and
>   third party cookies by default...
>   - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html

So try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```