# Webview cannot load files from static server on Android in release build

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a React Native app and having an issue with a webview.  This webview has the HTML hardcoded into it, but fetches additional files from a [static server](https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server) running in the app.

This works fine on iOS and it works on Android in development, but when I build an APK the files fail to be loaded into the webview.

I've made a [repo where the bug is reproduced](https://github.com/shawndoyle/webviewTest). Running this app with `npm run android` works as intended, and the HTML loads the image from the static server:

[image]

But when an APK is build (`npm run build`) and installed on the device, the image fails to load:

[image]

Why is the image not loading in the release build? I know that the static server is working because I can access it from the web browser while the app is running. I've read through the [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) docs and haven't found anything that explains this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68809436/how-to-use-a-webview-to-fetch-from-a-local-static-file-server-on-android

Comment: That was me, I posted this one instead with a reproducible and more detail

Comment: More detail? Still no html code.

Comment: I linked to a repo I made with all the code available

Comment: You haven't shared this file `rn-logo.png` from that repo. Also, this might be related to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/32339525/11104068. Can you check to see what is the target framework in develop and release for android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it! The problem is that the static server is not using HTTPS, so I needed to add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to the `application` tag of my `AndroidManifest.xml`